# get multiple file using express and angularJS

Tags: node.js, express

I want create a GET method to send multiple file; I have a table with the url; so i have the following code.

```
router.get('/assetImages/:assetImage_id',function(req,res){
  models.assetImage.findAll({ where: { imageURI: req.params.assetImage_id } }
  ).then(function(assets) {
    for (var i = assets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      res.sendfile("assets.imageURI");
    };
  }).catch(function(error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

but when I check the method using postman get "could not get any response" how if the server was not up; so i create the following code in angular to check the method.

```
loadByAssetIdAssetImages : function (assetId) {
    var auxResource = $resource(localPath + 'assetImages/' + assetId, null, {
                                    'query': { method:'GET', isArray: true }  }
                                );
    return auxResource.query().$promise;
}
```

the result is an object like `Object { data: null, status: 0, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }`

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP protocol was designed to send one file per request so [Express](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html) does not support sending multiple files. The only ways to send multiple files in a single request is to zip the files into a single archive and send the archive or use [multipart responses](https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/) (not recommended).

It is common practice to [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) your JavaScript and CSS files into a single file:

```
scripts
|
-- mainController.js
   userController.js

styles
|
-- main.css
   custom.css
```

into `scripts.js` and `styles.css`

But you don't do that with images. You can [minify and optimize](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) your images but those are typically retrieved one at a time from the server.

Your route looks like it is already getting an id but the id doesn't map to a unique image. Because of the way HTTP is designed you will probably need a unique image id for each image.